# Testing Application State in BDDs

Tags: unit-testing, testing, cucumber, tdd, bdd

Suppose I have an API that has three steps:

1. Create Quote
2. Add products to quote
3. Create Payment
4. Charge
5. Mutate (updates the document in my database)

I am writing a BDD for this API. My question is, should I check if the document is updated after the above steps have passed? Or that the document should not be mutated if any of the above steps have failed?

I ask this question as BDDs are for the product to read. So okay, the product should be able to see that the charge was successful, but does the product need to see if the database was updated? Isn't it too for technical for them?

What would be the correct way to test such steps, especially if they are the last step of your action chain?

Comment: I would write a separate scenario to validate that the document is updated, unless you are including a "And the document is updated" step for validation.  It would help to see your Gherkin syntax used now.

Comment: What I can't understand that the document is the application's state. Will we test the application state when the tests say 'Behaviour'?

Comment: I think the semantics might be misleading.  It's called behavioural because we're testing an entire process, I believe, and part of that process is functional - you need to confirm the state of the document since that is the purpose of the flow, to change it, just like you would need to validate the success of any flow, like landing on the right web page after a click, for example.  I'm not an expert, but in my tests, I can't think of any where I don't validate the end result(s).

Comment: What I thought (may be it's wrong) was that BDDs test the application's behaviour to the outside world? So for this case for example, the happy path would be that the quote is created successfully, the payment is created and is charged. Can we also test our internal stuff in the BDDs?

Comment: It all depends on the acceptance criteria.  If the product owner is satisfied that a message "document updated" for example is sufficient, then that's all you need.  If they expect it to be retrieved and validated, that should be expressed as part of the requirements and can be written as a single validation step (with a lot of underlying validation code) or a separate scenario with the validation steps listed out.  The only kinds of validation that automation does NOT typically do are things that are covered in unit testing by the developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I check if the document is updated after the above steps have passed? Or that the document should not be mutated if any of the above steps have failed?

The answer is "yes".

You should check if the document was updated when all steps passed.

You should have additional scenarios highlighting the fact the document is **not** updated if any of the steps fail. In fact, this feels like 5 separate scenarios:

1. All goes well, document is updated
2. First step fails, document not updated.
3. First step passes, but second step fails. Document not updated.
4. First and second steps pass, but third step fails. Document not updated.
5. First through third steps pass, but the "Charge" step fails. Document not updated.

While the product team is mainly thinking about scenario 1, if you introduce them to scenarios 2-5 you will quickly learn that they care about these scenarios as well.